# Tomcat port changed but Apache welcome page still showing on 8080

Tags: tomcat

I am attempting to add an application running under tomcat 8.5 to a server. I have 2 applications running under IIS ports 80 and 88. I wanted to change the tomcat port for the app to use port 8181. I changed the default port on tomcat/conf/server.xml everything and wanted to test completely internally. So i open a chrome browser and attempt to access my site using "http://localhost:8181/myapp" but I get the localhost refused connection error. So just to check all is ok, using chrome i navigate to http://localhost:8181 expecting to see the tomcat welcome page since I changed the default port but i get the connection refused error. If I navigate to http://localhost:8080 i get the tomcat welcome page. Am I missing something here? Shouldn't the welcome page show on port 8181 if I change the default port in my tomcat/conf/server.xml?

Comment: firewall issue ? is the process really listening on 8181 (check with netstat) ?

Comment: I'll have to use netstat to confirm the listening port. Thanks for the suggestion Eugene. But I'm still curious as to why the welcome page still displays on port 8080 if I've changed the default port to 8181?

Comment: any browser cache ? You'll check that with netstat too, if it is really listening or not.